# DataTables: Rearrange array entities during render

Tags: java, json, datatables

I use DataTables with server-side processing. The json object I receive contains an array of `LocalDateTime` element:

```
...
"SimpleDate": [ 2000,12,31,0,0 ]
...
```

My `columns` definition in the initialization script is the following:

```
"columns": [ 
             { "data": "SimpleDate"}
           ]
```

By default, the column is rendered comma-separated: 2000,12,31,0,0

**How can I change it to `31.12.2000`?**

I tried `columnDefs`and `render` like:

```
"columnDefs": [
        {   
            "render": function ( data, type, row ) {
                return data.2 + '.' + data.1 + '.' + data.0;
            },
            "targets": 0
        }
```

but this simply stops the table from rendering. I assume, accessing the array via `data.x`is not possible in this state.

So, how do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not accessing the elements of the data array properly.

```
        "render": function ( data, type, row ) {
            return data[2] + '.' + data[1] + '.' + data[0];
        },
```

Comment: You are right! The documentation of DataTables used `data.x` in the column section, so thought it would be the same way here. Thx

Answer (score 0):

Try something like below.

```
"columnDefs": ["targets": 0 , "data": "SimpleDate","render": function ( data, type, row ) { return data[2] + '.' + data[1]+ '.' + data[0]; }}
```